# how to use a .vue file in a html?

Tags: vue.js

I created a hello.vue file, now how to use this in a html file? I already setup a webpack,

```
<template>
<p>Hello</p>

<p>{{message}}</p>

</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
    data: {
        message: 'hello'
    }
}
</script>

<style>
p {
    font-size: 14px
}
</style>
```

Comment: When you say, use the component in an HTML file, do you mean use it in a new Vue() as a component?

Answer (score 2):

How do you want to use it?

Taking demonstation from official example: [vue-hackernews-2.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0). This is a component, so you import the [component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/master/src/components/Comment.vue) in another vue file like [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/6f0c0fef5eb06a469dcf15cb37dd1b55de57927e/src/views/ItemView.vue#L32):

```
import Comment from '../components/Comment.vue'
```

and you add in the list of components in [that vue instance](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/6f0c0fef5eb06a469dcf15cb37dd1b55de57927e/src/views/ItemView.vue#L60):

```
components: { Spinner, Comment },
```

Than you can use it in HTML like [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/6f0c0fef5eb06a469dcf15cb37dd1b55de57927e/src/views/ItemView.vue#L23):

```
<comment v-for="id in item.kids" :key="id" :id="id"></comment>
```

Comment: thanks, so we import the component into another .vue file, then use this .vue file in a html, is it possible to use the component directly in a html file?

Comment: @AngeloC A [vue component](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) will work inside a vue instance only, that is somewhere you will define `new Vue({...})`

Answer (score 2):

You just have to include your bundled .js file in your HTML file and include mounter div - so Vue could know where to execute the app.

Your index file could looks something like this (showing only body section)

```
...
<body>

  <div id="app"></div>

  <script src="bundle.js">
</body>
...
```

Your main Vue file could looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Hello from 'hello.vue'

const app = new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(Hello)
}).$mount('#app')
```

And in this way you can store all other components into the hello.vue.

This is probably way that you should use when you are building SPA.

Comment: do you have to run vue-cli?